# Remove only \ from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am getting a JSON string from a database query which selects data from multiple tables and return a list of records and then making JSON as,

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<JobNoQ>(query).ToList(); 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

and then I am getting following JSON:

```
"[{\"S1\":\"1\",\"S2\":\"202010010\",\"S30\":\"COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA\",\"S31\":\"Coca cola 1\",\"D1\":\"2015-07-01T00:00:00\",\"S5\":\"001\",\"S32\":\"Local\",\"S6\":\"T1\",\"S33\":\"By Road\",\"S10\":\"\"},
  {\"S1\":\"3\",\"S2\":\"202010010\",\"S30\":\"COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA\",\"S31\":\"Coca cola 1\",\"D1\":\"2015-07-01T00:00:00\",\"S5\":\"002\",\"S32\":\"Innter City\",\"S6\":\"T1\",\"S33\":\"By Road\",\"S10\":\"\"},
  {\"S1\":\"4\",\"S2\":\"202010010\",\"S30\":\"COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA\",\"S31\":\"Coca cola 1\",\"D1\":\"2015-07-01T00:00:00\",\"S5\":\"003\",\"S32\":\"International\",\"S6\":\"T2\",\"S33\":\"By Sea\",\"S10\":\"\"}
 ]"
```

I want to remove \ from this array. I have tried following:

```
1. string json = json.Replace("\"", " "); // It removes \ and all "" from the array. I only want to remove the \ 

2. string json = json.Replace(@"\", " "); // It does nothing
```

Comment: You're leaving something out. I don't see a possible way that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);` is generating property names with `"`s escaped. Further, your point that `json.Replace(@"\", " ");` does nothing leads me to believe that ***there are no blackslashes in the JSON*** and you're getting confused in your debug window.

Comment: @Rob Heh, I came to the same conclusion about the same time, but posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't have any backslashes in it, that's why replacing `@"\"` by `" "` has no effect. Your debugger is helpfully but confusingly translating your JSON string to the C# string syntax, which means your debugger is adding `\` before any `"` you see. If you actually let your code print the JSON string, you'll see they aren't there.

Comment: strange.. when I write this JSON in a file and check it, there were no \.
THANKS

Comment: @AwaisMahmood A tip for the future. If you click the magnifying glass in the debug window, it will pop up a new window with the string *exactly as it is*, without any escaping, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` backslash in C# is what's called an [escape character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). You must add another slash to escape the existing one like so:

```
string json = @"Test\string\replace";
json = json.Replace("\\", " ");
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

> Test string replace

With OP's string:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<JobNoQ>(query).ToList(); 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
json = json.Replace("\\", " ");
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
[{ "S1 ": "1 ", "S2 ": "202010010 ", "S30 ": "COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA ", "S31 ": "Coca cola 1 ", "D1 ": "2015-07-01T00:00:00 ", "S5 ": "001 ", "S32 ": "Local ", "S6 ": "T1 ", "S33 ": "By Road ", "S10 ": " "},
{ "S1 ": "3 ", "S2 ": "202010010 ", "S30 ": "COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA ", "S31 ": "Coca cola 1 ", "D1 ": "2015-07-01T00:00:00 ", "S5 ": "002 ", "S32 ": "Innter City ", "S6 ": "T1 ", "S33 ": "By Road ", "S10 ": " "},
{ "S1 ": "4 ", "S2 ": "202010010 ", "S30 ": "COCA COLA BEVERAGES PAKISTAN LTD. GUJRANWALA ", "S31 ": "Coca cola 1 ", "D1 ": "2015-07-01T00:00:00 ", "S5 ": "003 ", "S32 ": "International ", "S6 ": "T2 ", "S33 ": "By Sea ", "S10 ": " "}
]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, OP is walking a dangerous road in that there eventually **will** be a value which contains `\\` in the actual string. Best to address the application generating the JSON to make sure those backslashes aren't generated

Comment: I absolutely agree. Unfortunately OP didn't mention where the JSON string comes from so I don't know if he can do anything about it.

Comment: It didn't work. I am generating the JSON from a query result returned from database as var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<JobNoQ>(query).ToList();

Comment: Then put all of that information in your question so people know otherwise the answers will be wrong, I don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: @Equalsk Given that the OP already included that `json.Replace(@"\", " ")` doesn't work, and `"\\"` and `@"\"` mean exactly the same thing, you didn't need a crystal ball to know that this wouldn't work. You would just need a crystal ball to know what *would* work.

Comment: Awais - Thanks for the extra information. Unfortunately I still can't see why this isn't working for you. I've added the exact results I get in my answer in case that helps. @hvd You're right, I shouldn't be so miserable. Long day. Apologies.